# How to write a game on Python with lists and loop?

Tags: python, list, pycharm

I wrote the code for this game, but it has problems.
A game with one cube.
Before the game, 3 players write numbers from 1 to 6 on a piece of paper. A dice is thrown. Now the task is to get numbers from 1 to 6. The person who gets 1 can cross out 1 on his sheet of paper. Then next person. The winner is the first to cross out all the numbers one by one.

The idea is to create 3 lists and remove random number from each list in while loop

The Pycharm show this problem:
"if len(numbers_Berni) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

This is my code:

```
numbers_Berni = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
numbers_Rolf = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
numbers_Rosa = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

import random

print("Let's start, press ENTER to continue")

while len(numbers_Rolf) > 0 or len(numbers_Rosa) > 0 or len(numbers_Berni) > 0:

    print("Press ENTER to make Berni throw the dice")
    rand = random.choice(numbers_Berni)
    print("Berni's current numbers:")
    numbers_Berni = numbers_Berni.remove(rand)
    print(numbers_Berni)
    if len(numbers_Berni) == 0:
        print("Berni win")
        print("Game over")
        quit()

    print("Press ENTER to make Rolf throw the dice")
    rand = random.choice(numbers_Rolf)
    print("Rolf's current numbers:")
    numbers_Rolf = numbers_Rolf.remove(rand)
    print(numbers_Rolf)
    if len(numbers_Rolf) == 0:
        print("Rolf win")
        print("Game over")
        quit()

    print("Press SPACE to make Rolf throw the dice")
    rand = random.choise(numbers_Rosa)
    print("Rosa's current numbers:")
    numbers_Rosa = numbers_Rosa.remove(rand)
    print(numbers_Rosa)
    if len(numbers_Rosa) == 0:
        print("Rosa win")
        print("Game over")
        quit()
```

The idea is to create 3 lists and remove random number from each list in while loop

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code like `numbers_Berni = numbers_Berni.remove(rand)` causes `numbers_Berni` to become `None`. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an element from the list you don't reassign the result of the remove function back to the original list. remove() does NOT return anything. Change `numbers_Berni = numbers_Berni.remove(rand)` to just `numbers_Berni.remove(rand)`.

Obviously you have to change the statements for numbers_Rolf and numbers_Rosa as well.